# Understanding the parameter on callback function

Tags: javascript

`animate` takes a parameter `time`.

`requestAnimationFrame` is called with the callback function `animate`.

So far so good.

I assume `requestAnimationFrame` calls `animate` with the `time`, but how do you know for sure?

Code and Fiddle:

```
function animate(time) {
    document.getElementById("animated").style.left = (time - animationStartTime) % 2000 / 4 + "px";
    requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function start() {
    animationStartTime = window.performance.now();
    requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0uh2y6jz/)

Comment: Check the documentation.

Comment: I want to SLaks, but do you mean for callbacks in general or would you look requestAnimationFrame?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame

Comment: @radbyx: A callback is just a function.  The parameters are whatever are passed by whoever is calling the callback.

Comment: My goal is to learn how to find this in the documentation, but Im kinda lost, even with MrCode, so you someone please point it out for me, then I do it my self next time.

Comment: Wait I will try read MrCode link first carefully. I don't have to stress this out :)

Comment: Okay so here is the proof I guess, right? "The callback method is passed a single argument, a DOMHighResTimeStamp, which indicates the current time when callbacks queued by requestAnimationFrame begin to fire. " from MrCode's link.

Comment: Thanks alot guys, I actually learned alot :)